# SID missing in ID Token using spring authorization server

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I followed the spring authorization server sample but for some reason SID claim is missing in ID Token. SID claim is required for logout, I wonder how can I add it in ID Token to logout successfully.

I have three ways where user can login one using his username and password, second superadmin who can login as anyone and third using Azure AD. SID is present in Superadmin and Azure AD login but missing when user logs-in with username and password.

I am using spring authorization server 1.1.2.

Comment: I checked it 1 months ago  . for using in memory based in spring authorization server this is ok . but when using jdbc based SID will be null ;(

Comment: I keep client info and user info in db. I dont think I can use in-memory.

Comment: yes this is not recommended for production

Comment: Any solution to mitigate this issue. Any other way to logout user from auth server

Comment: "when using jdbc based SID will be null" @mamJavad please open an issue on the issue tracker for this.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg I created the issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/1361 with a sample to reproduce the issue

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg I think this issue was open one month ago

Answer (score 0):

i have the same behaviour as @user7090887

With InMemory Repository:
[image]
[image]
[image]
With JDBC Repository:

[image]
[image]
[image]

With InMemory i have the sid and with JDCBC its missing.
And when i try to logout i get an exception.
I forked the github repo from @user7090887 and created a working version.
I can push it when it helps.

```
#### Open in Browser
http://localhost:9009/oauth2/authorize?
    response_type=code
    &client_id=messaging-client
    &scope=openid
    &redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080
    &code_challenge=t3RzPLjc8NiO_mpmIuTJYi2P6Ps8y9jP6cphOhSNozw
    &code_challenge_method=S256
```

```
##### Get JWT Token
POST http://localhost:9009/oauth2/token?client_id=messaging-client
    &redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080
    &grant_type=authorization_code
    &scope=openid
    &code=y2VsiK-mdjsZQ9gr_qHJGV0uZKxfvyVzXXbq7D0x0tAE4QgYJoQXFRHTyjOF5tR9jgFB8zXn_Yj-icyGy9EIhFa6wVy6Hg9LZcSsSYTHc9PccI7PGitdNaZIWfvRpTex
    &code_verifier=mlZDBO_BNru6SRVHWhhAMJIsVCAdVZAL8VRTpy8hXBzcOJ92gKHtXPI3Agb0FF-l5NtYIbAcrl7bsHqSVJNDVWa0sjSoe0RvdwNy4Yz6StaQ-vd7uU0IRg-1tshE19PA

> {%
    client.global.set("AUTH_TOKEN",response.body.access_token);
    client.global.set("ID_TOKEN",response.body.id_token);
%}
```

```
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("messaging-client")
                .clientSecret("secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .redirectUri("http://localhost:8080")
                .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://localhost:8080")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireProofKey(true).requireAuthorizationConsent(false).build())
                .build();

        RegisteredClient deviceClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("device-messaging-client")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.DEVICE_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .scope("message.read")
                .scope("message.write")
                .build();
```

Comment: I fixed this issue by using custom authorization provider instead of using user details service.

Comment: @user7090887 i forgot to uncomment my OAuth2AuthorizationService and now it does not work. I implemented my own auth provider. How did u solve it?

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg are my clients misconfigured? When everything is fine i would add a working example to github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/…

Comment: Please open a new question and consider providing a minimal sample on GitHub that can be used to reproduce the problem. Trying to follow screenshots with debugger and JWT dumps will make it difficult to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will provide a working demo with postgres and some data.